# Face recognize using Opencv4Android SDK tutorial?

Tags: android, opencv, face-recognition

I am a student. Recently I've been building a Face recognize project using opencv but I dont know where to start.

I successfully build my Face detection using OpenCv4Android by reading opencv face detection sample.

Now I start to build **Face recognize** (using LBPH algorithm) part, I read Opencv document and search google for tutorial that I can actually follow but i failed (there lots of tutorial using javacv but I want to use OpenCv4Android instead) :(

can anyone help me with the step by step tutorial about what should i do to using face recognize in OpenCV4Android SDK? Big thanks to you.

Additional:

- I find out about FaceRecognizer.java class in opencv/contrib
- I find facerec.java in OpenCV4android folder
- I read somewhere and try the method FaceRecognize model = createLBPHFaceRecognizer() ---> but the method createLBPHFaceRecognizer() return error not found. where can i find and use this method?

Please help me what I need to do next? A lot of thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The createFisherFaceRecognizer() method (as well as the other 2 createXXXFaceRecognizer()) were skipped during the java wrapper code generation, it's a known, yet unsolved problem.

The best solution could be implementing it with jni/ndk. You will have to build:

- an .so file with the native c++ code, let's call it facerec.so an
  additional java wrapper class calling that, FisherFaceRecognizer.java

sadly, can't help much with ndk(no such thing here), but it worked nicely on desktop/eclipse (the dll/so would go right into your project folder), so here's the code (quite a wall of it).

// --- 8< --------- facerec.cpp -------------------------------

```
#include "jni.h"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_FisherFaceRecognizer_createFisherFaceRecognizer_10(JNIEnv* env, jclass);
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_FisherFaceRecognizer_createFisherFaceRecognizer_10(JNIEnv* env, jclass) {
    try {
        cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> pfr = cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer();
        pfr.addref(); // this is for the 2.4 branch, 3.0 would need a different treatment here
        return (jlong) pfr.obj;
    } catch (...) {
        jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        env->ThrowNew(je, "sorry, dave..");
    }
    return 0;
}

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_FisherFaceRecognizer_createFisherFaceRecognizer_11(JNIEnv* env, jclass, jint num_components);
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_FisherFaceRecognizer_createFisherFaceRecognizer_11(JNIEnv* env, jclass, jint num_components) {
    try {
        cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> pfr = cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer(num_components);
        pfr.addref();
        return (jlong) pfr.obj;
    } catch (...) {
        jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        env->ThrowNew(je, "sorry, dave..");
    }
    return 0;
}

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_FisherFaceRecognizer_createFisherFaceRecognizer_12(JNIEnv* env, jclass, jint num_components, jdouble threshold);
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_FisherFaceRecognizer_createFisherFaceRecognizer_12(JNIEnv* env, jclass, jint num_components, jdouble threshold) {
    try {
        cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> pfr = cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer(num_components,threshold);
        pfr.addref();
        return (jlong) pfr.obj;
    } catch (...) {
        jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        env->ThrowNew(je, "sorry, dave..");
    }
    return 0;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

// --- 8< --------- FisherFaceRecognizer.java -----------------

```
import org.opencv.contrib.FaceRecognizer;
import org.opencv.core.Core;

public class FisherFaceRecognizer extends FaceRecognizer {

    static{ System.loadLibrary("facerec"); }

    private static native long createFisherFaceRecognizer_0();
    private static native long createFisherFaceRecognizer_1(int num_components);
    private static native long createFisherFaceRecognizer_2(int num_components, double threshold);

    public FisherFaceRecognizer () {
        super(createFisherFaceRecognizer_0());
    }
    public FisherFaceRecognizer (int num_components) {
        super(createFisherFaceRecognizer_1(num_components));
    }
    public FisherFaceRecognizer (int num_components, double threshold) {
        super(createFisherFaceRecognizer_2(num_components, threshold));
    }
}
```

once you got all this compiled (congrats!!), you would call it like this:

```
FaceRecognizer  facerec = new FisherFaceRecognizer();
   facerec.load("/sdcard/smile.yml"); // note, that it can't read from apk or zip, so you need to copy it somewhere

   Mat img = ...//test face
   int [] label = new int[1];
   double [] conf = new double[1];
   facerec.predict(img, label, conf);
```

Comment: It's better to write up what to do and post that as an answer rather than posting links as links may become invalid and then your answer is pretty useless. You can otherwise post the link as a comment.

Comment: We can use JavaCPP to get this working much more easily. Here is a sample demonstrating this: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/OpenCVFaceRecognizer.java